# Display first element

Tags: html, css, display

If I have:

But with result only for first .first. The first .second is still with display none.

```css
.first {
  display: none;
}

.first:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}

.second {
  display: none;
}

.second:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">first</div> //I want to display only this
<div class="ro">ro</div>
<div class="first">first</div> //I want to hide this
<div class="ro">ro</div>
<div class="first">first</div> //I want to hide this
<div class="ro">ro</div>
<div class="first">first</div> //I want to hide this
<div class="ro">ro</div>
<div class="second">second</div> //I want to display only this
<div class="eo">eo</div>
<div class="second">second</div> //I want to hide this
<div class="eo">eo</div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear: what do you want to show exactly? Do you want to show all div having class `.first` or `.second`?

Comment: The first element that have the class .first and the first element that have the class .second

Comment: Ok so please refine better in the question description

Comment: Please attach a screenshot or drawing of the desired outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [subsequent-sibling combinator ~](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

```css
.first {
    display: block;
}
.first ~ .first {
    display: none;
}
.second {
    display: block;
}
.second ~ .second {
    display: none;
}
```

With the formula `.first ~ .first` you're instructing to apply `display: none` to all elements with class `.first` preceded by another element with class `.first`.